# js array not displaying content

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//array
window.onload = myFunction();
function myFunction(){
var stroreRandom = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 25; i++){

var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 78) + 1);
storeRandom.push(random);
x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = storeRandom;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <Table id = table>
        <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell">1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell">2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell">3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 4>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 5>5</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 6>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 7>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 8>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 9>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 10>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 11>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 12>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 13>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 14>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 15>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 16>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 17>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 18>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 19>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 20>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 21>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 22>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 23>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 24>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 25>5</td>
        </tr>

    </Table>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 78.</p>

<button id = "button" onclick = "myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>       

<!--
<script>
    
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 78) + 1);
}</script>
-->

 <script src = "js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the objective is to make a bingo card, that self generates 25 unique numbers from 1-78, I decided to do this by storing the random numbers in an array and assigning them to the table  through appendChild but I can't get to that point because I cant get the array to store information

There are no issues with path

Comment: javascript is case sensitive with its variable. strorerandom != stroreRandom

Answer (score 2):

There are errors coming which can be seen in console.

1. `innerhtml` has to be `innerHTML`
2. `storeRandom` case to be same across function as `strorerandom` is not same as `stroreRandom`

```js
//array
window.onload = myFunction();
function myFunction(){
var storeRandom= [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 25; i++){

var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 78) + 1);
storeRandom.push(random);
x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML= storeRandom;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <Table id = table>
        <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell">1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell">2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell">3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 4>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 5>5</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 6>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 7>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 8>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 9>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 10>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 11>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 12>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 13>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 14>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 15>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 16>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 17>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 18>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 19>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 20>5</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 21>1</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 22>2</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 23>3</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 24>4</td>
            <td class = "bingocell" id = 25>5</td>
        </tr>

    </Table>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 78.</p>

<button id = "button" onclick = "myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>       

<!--
<script>
    
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 78) + 1);
}</script>
-->

 <script src = "js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is case sensitive with its variable. strorerandom != stroreRandom

Comment: Hi it was changed but the issue hasn't changed